How to edit the outlines of a PDF file on Android?
How can I add, delete and edit the outlines (also called table of contents in Adobe reader, not bookmarks) of a PDF file, while viewing it on an Android phone?

This may be better asked on [android.se] or [softwarerecs.se], but check the Help Center for each first.

Already posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/258122/44325
